# Increase timeout in Langchain AzureMLOnlineEndpoint

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, langchain

I am trying to increase the timeout parameter in Langchain which is used to call an LLM. This is my code:

```
from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain.llms.azureml_endpoint import DollyContentFormatter, AzureMLOnlineEndpoint
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
import os

formatter_template = "Write a {word_count} word essay about {topic}."

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["word_count", "topic"], template=formatter_template
)

content_formatter = DollyContentFormatter()

llm = AzureMLOnlineEndpoint(
    endpoint_api_key='',
    endpoint_url='',
    model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.8, "max_tokens": 300},
    content_formatter=content_formatter,
    timeout=120
)

chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
print(chain.run({"word_count": 100, "topic": "how to make friends"}))
```

The error I am getting is:

```
> File /anaconda/envs/langchain/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py:282, in Chain.__call__(self, inputs, return_only_outputs, callbacks, tags, metadata, include_run_info)
280 except (KeyboardInterrupt, Exception) as e:
...
\-\> 1099         return self.\_sslobj.read(len, buffer)
1100     else:
1101         return self.\_sslobj.read(len)  
> timeout: The read operation timed out  
> Need to increase timeout.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the issue don't come from your timeout, this is because it isn't connected to Endpoint.

In my opinion, I use their environment variables as follow:

```
os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"]="azure"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"]="2023-07-01-preview"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"]= # Your Endpoint
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]= # Your Azure OpenAI resource key
os.environ["OPENAI_CHAT_MODEL"]="gpt-35-turbo-16k"
```

I use the AzureChatOpenAI and AzureOpenAIEmbeddings for my chatbot. My langchain version is **0.0.339**. You can try to use it with their environment variables.